# Can you call friend function as you call member function?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

```
class fraction
{
    long num;
    long den;

public:
    fraction(long,long);
    fraction();
    ~fraction();
    fraction( const fraction & );
    void setNum(long);
    void setDen(long);
    friend void print(const fraction&);
};


void print(const fraction& s)
{
    cout<<s.num<<" "<<s.den<<endl;
}
```

and can be called as

```
fraction f1(5,1);
print(f1);
```

Can it be modified in some way so that we can call it as `f1.print()` ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Only members can be accessed using the member-access syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can it be modified in some way ?*

```
// forward declare fraction
class fraction;

// declare funtion in global scope
void print(const fraction&);

class fraction
{
public:
    /* ... */

    // declare function as friend
    friend void print(const fraction&);

    // add member function
    void print() const { ::print(*this); }
};

void print(const fraction& s)
{
    cout<< s.num << " " << s.den << endl;
}

int main()
{
    fraction f1(5,1);
    f1.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The word "friend" means that the function or class mentioned is a "friend" of your class, and gives the "friend" permission to access your protected or private members as if they were public. The only effect of "friend" is on the code inside the friend function or friend class. Apart from that, "friend" does nothing. It doesn't change the way that the "friend" function is called or used at all.

Answer (score 0):

A friend is not a member function of your class, and cannot be called like your member function, a friend function only means that this function have access to all members of your class.